# haskell list of tuples, with unique tuples

Tags: list, haskell, tuples, list-comprehension

I come from a Python and Java background so Haskell is quite different for me. I'm trying little activities to learn but I am stuck on this .

I have an ordered list of tuples, [(name, studentNumber)], and I want to filter this list so that each student and each studentNumber appears only once. Since the tuples are ordered, I want to keep the first instance of a name or studentNumber and remove any others that may show up.

I tried doing a list comphrenshion, but I'm not sure how to check if a name or number has already been added to the list.

Comment: The simplest solution would be `nub`, but since it can't rely on the list being sorted (you meant that, right? Lists are always ordered, so it makes no sense to state that explicitly), it will (unless I'm grossly mistaken) be less efficent than something tailored to that condition.

Comment: What should be the output if this is the input? `[("Anne", 3), ("Anne", 5), ("Bob", 5)]`

Comment: I meant ordered such that the first tuple means they are the first student registered, the second tuple is the second student and so on. I need to preserve this order!

Comment: @dave4420 it should output [("Anne", 3), ("Bob", 5)]

Comment: You may also want to take a look at `Data.Set` or `Data.Map`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds as if you'd want (as a first, inefficient approximation) something like this:

```
import Data.List (nubBy)
import Data.Function (on)

filt = nubBy ((==) `on` snd) . nubBy ((==) `on` fst)
```

The first call to `nubBy` will result in a list in which each name appears only once, and that will then be passed to the second, resulting in a list in which each number appears only once.

Just using `nub` will result in a list in which each `(name,number)` pair occurs only once; there might still be repetitions of names with different numbers and numbers with different names.

(Of course something custom with an accumulator would be faster.)

Comment: Thanks! I found nubBy on another SO post but didn't think far enough to do that! This works great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can spy on `Data.List` [sources](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Data-List.html#nub) and write your extended `nub` function:

```
type Student = (Name, Number)
type Name = String
type Number = Int

unique :: [Student] -> [Student]
unique = go [] [] 
  where
    go unames unumbers (s@(name, number):ss)
      | name `elem` unames || number `elem` unumbers = go unames unumbers ss
      | otherwise = s : go (name:unames) (number:unumbers) ss
    go _ _ [] = []
```

Should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To unique-ify a list there's always the `nub` function from the prelude, I think that should do exactly what you need!

Comment: [Never use the `nub` function.](https://github.com/nh2/haskell-ordnub#dont-use-nub) It is quadratic.